# Why "dirty" flag appears only after second form change?

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I using redux-form in my project.
And there is one problem:
when user changes one of the form fields the "dirty" flag will be equal to "false", but if user change any field one more time it will return dirty == true.
I expect to get dirty == true once the any field will be changed.

```
class Form extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}
           onChange={() => console.log(this.props.dirty)}>
       {this.props.children}
     </form>
   )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({form: 'form'})(Form)
```

Comment: I tried reproducing this, but in my case it works just fine. Do you have a code example somewhere that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't provide more details.
'onChange' event fires every time the field was changed, so problem with 'dirty' property and I have no idea how to fix it.